# Selenium and JavascriptExecutor, running existing code on page

Tags: java, selenium

There is this line of code on a page that I would like to execute:

```
<a href="javascript:clickOnNode(0,4)" shape=""></a><img name="someimage" src="someimage">
```

It's a clickable link and I would like to know how to just run that code rather than using "find element by".

My code that I've been running is below, however it doesn't work.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("clickOnNode(0,4);");
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDITS:**

This is the code I'm currently using.

```
driver.navigate().to("someWebsite.com");

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("clickOnNode(0,4);");

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("img[name='nodeIcon4']")));
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[name='nodeIcon4']")).click();
```

Here is the output I am getting when I run the code:

> org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: Error executing JavaScript

and for the wait for nodeIcon4 lines:

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: img[name='nodeIcon4'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

I also tried running pburgr's code with

```
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@name,'nodeIcon4')]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@name,'nodeIcon4')]")).click();
```

and got the following error:

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //a[contains(@name,'nodeIcon4')]

For more sanity checking:

- I know that having the hard sleep command is bad. You can scold me later ;-)
- I am limited to using IE and the webpage automatically emulates IE5. The webpage will not correctly load for anything later than IE5.
- I am pretty sure that I have security levels for zones correctly setup because I can log on to other sites and interact with elements on the page with my code. Unless the emulation is messing that up somehow.

I can give more details as needed.

Comment: could be just a matter of synchronization. Try solution mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425827/selenium-call-javascript-function-on-page

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @KirilS. I tried running "clickOnNode(0,4);" in the console, but it returns "'clickOnNode' is undefined". I also had my code pause for 10 seconds to allow ample time for the page to load. I still receive a "Error executing JavaScript" error.

Comment: Because you failed to execute `clickOnNode(0,4)` in DevTool's console manually, even you had wait 10 seconds for page load.  I think maybe you need to click/expand something on that page which will make the browser to load the javascript file which include the function definition of `clickOnNode()`.   I guess the javascript file includes the `clickOnNode()` is not loaded when the page opened first time.

Comment: What's your problem with finding the element and clicking it?

Comment: Can you show your full code that reads the page and the error(s) you're getting?

Comment: Try `wait_sec(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(@name,'someimage')]")));` before executing the script. If the expected contidion fails, yong is right. The wait method `public WebDriverWait wait_sec(WebDriver driver, int sec) {return new WebDriverWait(driver, sec);}`

Comment: Sorry for the late replies guys, it was a long weekend for me and I'm finally coming back to this problem. @TeeKea I updated my post with a chunk of my code, let me know if you need more info. My problem with being unable to find any elements is just that. My code cannot seem to find any elements on the page.

Comment: @pburgr I tried your suggestion and it was a no go. I even tried the following line `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("logout")));` and clicking it, but I am getting nothing. The element is the following `<A onclick=logoutIETP(); id=logout title="Logout PINPOINT a">Log out: <SPAN id=span_login_user>someuser</SPAN></A>`

Comment: Can you share the page you're trying to access?

Comment: The page is on an intranet. It uses some software called Corena Pinpoint.